# Adding a UITabBar and tabbaritems to the UITabBar through code ( NOTE: I don't want to implement TabBarController )

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have searched a lot and beleive me i have come across many questions and sample codes but none of them fit my requirement , it's crazy how can there not be an answer for this.

My requirements specifically:-
1. I want a UITabBar not a UITabBarController
2. I want it to be on the top-right corner of my UIView
3. I want two tab bar items on it( need not be assiciated with two view controllers)

Now what i did was

```
UITabBar *myTabBar=[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:myTabFrame];
[self.view addSubView:myTabBar];
myTabBar.delegate=self;
```

Now i am stuck at how do i add tabbar items to this UITabBar.

I guess it's probably easy but every code i found has TabBarController added to it, but i don't want to use tabbarcontroller as for starters it only comes on the bottom of the screen , plus that's not the requirement.

Comment: Thank You Problem Solved :)  Did as jonkroll suggested .

Comment: Sudhanshu, this question is fantastic. How, though is the frame properly set? Do we use constraints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by creating the items you want for your tab bar, adding them to an array, and then calling the UITabBar method `setItems:animated:`

```
UITabBarItem *firstItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:firstImage tag:1];
UITabBarItem *secondItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:secondImage tag:2];

NSArray *itemsArray = @[firstItem, secondItem];

[myTabBar setItems:itemsArray animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank You , actually i was adding the items but i set my frame wrong so coudln't see it on the scren :( , but thank you , helped my find my problem :) thanks

Comment: Its the little things that are hard to find... Thank you